# Identity Server 3 - invalid_grant - Refresh token already used

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver3

In our application, we periodically encounter a scenario where the user requests a new token at the same time when we're automatically refreshing the token in the background (via JS.)

Both requests are using the refresh token & hitting the token endpoint.

If the automatic request finishes first, the user-initiated request results in an error. This is because both requests are trying to use the same refresh token but since it can only be used once, it's consumed by the first request and the second request gets 400 Bad Request.

My question is: What's the best way to handle the 400 response for the second request? Ideally, I want to silently retry the request and the user should be none-the-wiser.

Comment: My first thought is that upon a 400 response from the identity server, the client app should do a refresh (or redirect) in order to refresh the claims principle to include the new refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs, the ultimate fall-back has to be reauthenticating - IdentityServer is doing nothing wrong, the ball is in your court.

But - you should be able to make this situation impossible by synchronising the automatic token refresh and the user-driven token request. If the refresh token lives in your application in one place, then you can regulate access to it via some kind of lock/release mechanism.

This npm package looks like it'd do it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lock

Alternatively you could synchronise calls on the server by subclassing the relevant IdentityServer component, and using a per-client lock there - but IdentityServer is already complicated, it would require many locks in one place, and it wouldn't be easily scalable to multiple server instances.